# IE8 - Parallax Content Slider autoplay issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Is there an option to hide arrows when mouse is not over pictures in IE8? I spend a lot of time trying to do this but nothing that I've tried works, please help me

Comment: And what is cslider?

Comment: I'm sorry it's actually Parallax Content Slider from this page - http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

In style.css and style2.css of the [Parallax Content Slider plugin](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/03/15/parallax-content-slider-with-css3-and-jquery/), look for this rule:

```
    da-slider:hover .da-arrows span {
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

Adding an IE8-specific rule that overrides it will do the trick.